# Calling method from another class unsuccessful

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a main class called Main.java and the other class called Movements.java

I tried calling upon a method from the Movements.java into the Main.java but it was not what I expected.

Main.java:

```
package game;

public class Main {

Movements shift = new Movements();

public void main String(String[] args) {

   while (true){
//body here//
   }
}

public static void startProgram {
//body here//
}

public static int variableName {
//body here//
}

public static boolean isInputValid {
//body here//
}

public Chess(){
shift.analyzeInput();
shift.makeTurn();
}

}
```

Movements.java:

```
package game;
public class Movements {

    public static void analyzeInput(String info){
    StringTokenizer token = null;
    EasyWriter show = new EasyWriter();

    int tally = 0;
    info = info.toLowerCase();
    info = info.trim();

    String[] array = new String[100]; 

    token = new StringTokenizer(info);

    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
        array[tally] = token.nextToken();
        tally++;
    }

    if (tally > 0 && tally < 4){
        if (tally == 1){
            if (array[0].equals("resign")){
                if (Main.timeForWhitePlayer){
                    show.println("Black wins");
                    System.exit(1);
                }else{
                    show.println("White wins");
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }else if (array[0].equals("draw")){
                if (Main.drawRequest == true){
                    show.println("It's a draw");
                    System.exit(1);
                }else{
                    show.println("You must ask the opponent if they are willing to call the game a draw first.");
                }
            }else{
                show.println("Invalid input. Please try again. ");
            }
        }else if (tally == 2) {
            Main.presentPosition = array[0];
            Main.nextPosition = array[1];
            if (Main.presentPosition.length() == 2 && Main.nextPosition.length() == 2 ){

                makeTurn();
            }else{
                show.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
            }
    }

    Main.presentPosition = null;
    Main.nextPosition = null;
    Main.thirdArgument = null;
    }

    public static void makeTurn() {
    //body in here//
    }
}
```

I'm using Eclipse IDE and it states that Syntax error on token "makeTurn", Identifier expected after this token. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Please show the **exact** and full error message. Also why create an instance to call a static method? Why not simply call it off of the class name? You're showing package name but not showing class declaration -- probably most important here and certainly much more important than the package declaration.

Comment: Three things.  You need to provide a little bit more code (namely the names of the classes you're using).  Further, you're declaring a `new Move()` but referencing it by `Movements`.  Lastly, `makeTurn` is a static method - you *do not require* an instance of a class to call it.

Comment: Do you have a Move class?

Comment: object creation not required for static methods just do `ClassName.methd()`

Comment: You still don't provide enough context. That `---code above this line---` is of key importance. For all we know you could be nesting methods or miss counting curly braces, or who knows. More please.

Comment: @singhakash I tried doing that but to no avail

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my code is over 200+ lines. If I post the full code, I'm afraid I'll compromise the clarity of the issue.

Comment: @trancer: then you need to hone down your code to the smallest that reproduces your error. But I think that my answer/guess is correct, that your calls above are naked in the class. Please try to isolate the error and clarify your question. Look at things through our shoes -- how can we guess what might be wrong given snippets that don't show the error?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I hope this could give you an idea as to what my code contains. If not, I'll try to post a little more details about the code

Comment: My answer is correct -- you're making calls naked out in the class. Don't do that. Move that code into a method or constructor.

Comment: I've edited the Main.java file by relocating the `Movements shift = new Movements();` and adding `public Chess`. Would this be a viable solution? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Sorry. I selected the wrong answer but I have rectified it @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: `public Chess() { }` ... that's an invalid constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, you're calling `shift.makeTurn();` outside of any method or constructor, naked in the class. If so, you can't do that as you must make method calls that don't initialize a variable within a method or constructor or some similar block (static initializer block for instance).

For instance, to simplify, assuming you have a Movements class like so:

```
public class Movements {
   // looks like this should not be static
   public void makeTurn() {

   }
}
```

and a Main class like so:

```
public class Main {
   Movements shift = new Movements();
   shift.makeTurn();  // you can't call this here!

   public Main() {
      shift.makeTurn();  // but you can do it here!
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Movements shift = new Movements();       
      shift.makeTurn();  // or you can do it here!
   }
}
```

Edit: my assumption was correct -- you're making method calls outside of any method or constructor and the solution is simple: don't do that. Put those calls in whatever method or constructor they belong.

Other issues:

- Your code has static overload -- overuse of the static modifier, making it a non-OOP program.
- You're making way too many direct references of one class's fields in another, and this leads to code with lots of connections (called highly coupled code). This can lead to very hard to debug errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an instance since the method is static. You can simply call `Movements.makeTurn()`. And also I guess you meant to change `Movements mv = new Move();` to `Movements mv = new Movements();` if you do not have a `Move` class. If you do, then it must extend the type `Movements`

Comment: I tried using `Movements.makeTurn();` but it doesn't solve my problem @tamehog

Comment: @trancer: (**Again**) Please improve your question. You're forcing everyone to read minds and to guess -- don't do that since we're terrible at this sort of game.

Comment: @TameHog my code is 200+ lines long. I scared it would be so long that it would not display clearly the relevant lines that are causing the issue

Comment: @trancer could you post a little more. We need more than two lines to create a good answer

Comment: @TameHog I edited the question to give a picture as to how my code looks like in terms of the classes and methods available

Comment: @trancer your code isn't in a method. You must put the code in a method

Comment: ...As was stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your class `Main`.  It's confusing.  `main` is what we call the method we use as the program entry point.

`shift.makeTurn()` is not within any method, constructor, or initialiser so you need to move it.  You also need to decide if `makeTurn()` needs access to any properties that will be different in different instances of `Movements` (you called one `shift`).  If so you can't make it static.

If you want to call using

```
shift.makeTurn();
```

then turn this:

```
public static void makeTurn() {
```

into this:

```
public void makeTurn() {
```

Otherwise do what @TameHog told you to do.

A static method isn't bound to an instance like `shift`.  It's bound to a class like `Movements`.  It's all about what makeTurn() needs access to.  Though non static is considered more flexable.  If you understand that you should be able to decide which to do on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods within the `class` definition. Instead you must call the method within a method or initializer.

Using a method

```
package game;

public class Main {
public void main String(String[] args) {
   shift.makeTurn();
   while (true){
//body here//
   }
}

public static void startProgram {
//body here//
}

public static int variableName {
//body here//
}

public static boolean isInputValid {
//body here//
}

Movements shift = new Movements();
}
```

Or, with the instantiation in the function,

```
package game;

public class Main {
public void main String(String[] args) {
   Movements shift = new Movements();
   shift.makeTurn();
   while (true){
//body here//
   }
}

public static void startProgram {
//body here//
}

public static int variableName {
//body here//
}

public static boolean isInputValid {
//body here//
}
}
```

Or with an initialiser

```
package game;

public class Main {
public void main String(String[] args) {

   while (true){
//body here//
   }
}

public static void startProgram {
//body here//
}

public static int variableName {
//body here//
}

public static boolean isInputValid {
//body here//
}

Movements shift = new Movements();
{ shift.makeTurn();}
}
```

Comment: what if I want to import the `analyzeInput` method which has a parameter contain in the brackets? I edited the Main.java to show you what I've done. @spudowiar

Comment: `shift.analyzeInput(info)` where `info` is the parameter, e.g. `shift.analyzeInput("resign");`